# French carte de sejour holder with new passport, need to carry old passport with vignette when travelling?

Tags: france

I have a titre de sejour (TDS) -- a card separate from my passport -- in France which is valid for another 2 years. I recently renewed my [non-European] passport. I have my old passport which has been cancelled (holes in the cover), but which holds my vignette (what acted as a TDS in my first year in France).

I know I need to carry/present my TDS when I enter France, but before I renewed my old passport, I noticed that at the border, the officer always opens my passport to the page where the vignette is anyway to check that, even though I have presented my (newer) TDS.

*Do I have to carry my old passport which is where my vignette is?* Or am I okay to just travel with my new passport and TDS alone?

Comment: Why don't you try an experiment: carry the old passport the first time you re-enter France, but don't show it.  If the immigration officer asks for it, you can show it; if not, you can probably omit it for future trips.  Either way, you can ask the officer to explain the rules.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing this if I don't have a more concrete answer before my next trip. My main hesitation is that my next trip outside FR is a few months long and requires a few location changes, so I'd like to minimise the probability that I'd lose the old passport in case I need it later. Mainly curious whether anyone knew of the necessity of the vignette (or not) offhand. But if not, I'll do that and answer my own question here!

Comment: Strange, they never seem to even look at that in my case.  They just look at my passport and don't really seem to interrogate it much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the suggestion of phoog above, I did a little experiment.

I left France for 3 months and carried the old passport but did not present it at the border. **I presented only my titre de sejour and current passport, and that was fine.**

I have since exited and re-entered France from non-EU locations several times. I have not been asked about this once, although I continue to present my titre de sejour along with my passport.